# Compute for k=0...N: $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left ( e^{\frac{j2k\pi}{N}} \right )^{n}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Compute the following for $k=0,\dots,N$$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left ( e^{\frac{j2k\pi}{N}} \right )^{n}$$

Here I used the finite sum formula: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}ar^k = a\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$

Then used euler transformation, $e^{ix}=\cos x + i\sin x$

from which I got $\frac{1-cos2k\pi -jsin2k\pi}{1 - cos\frac{2k\pi}{N} - jsin\frac{2k\pi}{N}}$

And now I don't know what to do this with "compute for $k=0,\dots,N$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k = 0$ or $N$, each summand has value $1$, so the sum equals $N$. If $1 \le k < N$, then $z := \exp(2\pi j k/N)$ is different from $1$. So the sum equals

$$\sum_{j = 0}^{N-1} z^j = \frac{z^N - 1}{z - 1} = \frac{1 - 1}{z - 1} = 0.$$

Comment: But when we applied the eulers formula, like I said it gives $\frac{1-cos2k\pi -jsin2k\pi}{1 - cos\frac{2k\pi}{N} - jsin\frac{2k\pi}{N}}$ and either k=0 or N, it gives us $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: When $k = 0$ or $k = N$, $\exp(2\pi j k/N) = 1$. So in those cases, your sum is $1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 [\text{$N$ times}] = N$.

Comment: Yes actually first I found 0 as well. But then I thought about question again. It only says $k=0,\dots,N$. We don't know if k is an integer or N goes to infiniti. Here I'm stuck

Comment: In this context, you are to assume that $k$ is an integer between $0$ and $N$ inclusive.

Comment: Similarly what would happen in a case like this: 
$k=0,\dots,N$

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}cos\frac{2k\pi}{N}n$

Comment: Use the identity $\cos \theta = (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta})/2$, $\theta \in \Bbb R$, and the results I displayed in my answer to see what happens.